# ASP.NET + Bootstrap Modal remote page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with Bootstrap for the Views. I have a button on the _Layout.cshtml page that I want to use to load a modal to display another page in the project directory.

Button on the _Layout page in Views/Shared :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" data-toggle="modal" href="Modals/testModal.html" data-target="#signUpModal">Sign up</a>
```

The page I want to load is stored in Views/Shared/Modals/testModal.html.

testModal.html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signUpModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign up form</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create User</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

It works fine when I have the modal included on the same page but I cannot seem to load it this way.

Comment: Have you check your console? Do you get any errors? And have you confirmed that the href path is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can't server up static files from within the Views folder it is only intended for MVC.

You need to create another folder and reference them from there i.e.

```
/Modals/testModal.html
```

You also need to add an ignore route to RegisterRoutes, it should look something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            // Below is the ignore rule
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");

            // custom routing if any
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

[image: Screen shot displaying static file]

For more info see here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx/

Comment: I've done that and it still doesn't load.. I'm not sure why but it seems like when I click on the button not even the request is sent. The path is showing correctly when I hover over it though.

Comment: Sorry updated the route ignore, I forgot about that.